# Is it possible to use both static and dynamic libs in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a project that uses some libraries that I wrote. On my main project, I am linking these libraries using

```
LIBS += -LPATH_TO_LIBS -lsomename
```

so the usual stuff. If I build all my libs as dynamic lib, it works fine. If I build all my libs as static I got linker errors because for some reason `g++` prioritizes dynamic libs I guess. But If I add `-Wl,-Bstatic` to my linker options, then that works fine too. Here is my problem:

I want to use static versions of some libs and dynamic versions of others. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problem using both static and dynamic libraries. The following command line should work:

```
g++ object1.o object2.o -lmydynamiclibrary -lmystaticlibrary -o binary
```

Note that static libraries should be put after object files and dynamic libraries in the command line because object files and libs import/export symbols are analyzed in order and for static libs the linker only keeps the exported symbols that are known to be necessary at that moment.

*if you want a more detailed answer you should tell us what is the command line executed for the linker and what is the error you get*